# "Unable to mount Android, Error initialising camera: -60: Could not lock the device" when connecting a Samsung Galaxy S2 via MTP

Tags: mount, android, mtp

Whenever I connect my Samsung Galaxy S2 phone (running Android 4.0) via USB using an MTP connection one of two messages always pops up, either:

**Unable to mount Android: Error initialising camera: -60: Could not lock the device**

[image: Error initialising camera: -60: Could not lock the device]

**or: Unable to mount Android: Error initialising camera: -53: Could not claim the USB device**

[image: Error initialising camera: -53: Could not claim the USB device]

The phone however does mount successfully and I can add and delete files etc. I would just like to understand what the error message means, googling only seems to bring up descriptions of people mounting digital cameras and this doesn't seem relevant for a mobile phone.

Comment: I thought MTp didn't work on CM9, works fine in MIUI and Samsung Stock ROMs.

Comment: @UriHerrera I found it the other way round, MTP works fine with CM9 but not with stock

Comment: Before going too far with this. I suggest you create a new user (I'll call it newuser here) Logon as newuser and try connecting your MTP device. As "myself" I get that same error, as newuser , it works. I think something happened in the past copying $HOME around from one install to another. The 'file' .gvfs gets messes up, but it seems to be more than that.

Comment: Might there be a virtual machine running, by any chance? I got this error too when running Windows 7 as guest. The Win7 guest was somehow grabbing the camera before Ubuntu did and thus foiling up the permissions. After I disconnected the camera from Windows things proceeded normally in Linux.

Comment: @MarisanoJames I started to get the second error message after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. I did not get any error messages in Ubuntu 12.04. I always had Win 7 in virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

I found that when I was plugged into a usb 3.0 port I got the following messages:

```
usbfs: USBDEVFS_CONTROL failed cmd gvfs-gphoto2-vo rqt 33 rq 102 len 0 ret -71
```

But when I plugged into a usb 2.0 port it worked.

Comment: this made it for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this : http://www.tuxtrix.com/2011/07/how-to-access-samsung-galaxy-s-ii-usb.html . It worked for me

**Note** : In Android 4.0 with TW launcher, you need to click on "more" to get the option.

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort in to answer. I know how to connect the phone with mass storage, my question was related to why does the error message appear and what does it when connecting via MTP

Answer (score 0):

I get this as well, but to be honest it's a bug and there's not much to question about it - but instead report it. Should not happen.